# Prove $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)= 2ac + 2bd$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, complex-numbers

*I arrived at this question on reading about another issue, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105387/424260).*

I am unable to prove the above, even though attempt geometrical proof below:
Take $a,b,c,d$ as magnitudes of quantities (lengths). As no product term of $ab, cd$ is given so assuming right angle triangles (with right angle between sides of lengths $a,b$ & $c,d$), then $(a^2+b^2)$ leads to square of hypotenuse, let $h_1 (=\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$, similarly $(c^2+d^2)$ too, i.e. $h_2^2$. Their multiplication is $h_1^2h_2^2$.

The r.h.s. gives twice the product of sides of different triangles, i.e. $(a,c)$ & $(b,d)$. This algebraically means that the two triangles' sides should be multiplied. This in the simplest case is of a rectangle with sides of lengths $a,b,c,d$ with length $a=c, b=d$. This  leads to r.h.s. as $2(a^2+b^2)$, so it leads to twice the sum of two hypotenuse's (let, $h_a, h_b$) square, i.e. $2(h_a^2+h_b^2)$. It satisfies for rectangle with side lengths $a=c, b=d$ & also for square with $a=b=c=d$. But, except for this simplest case, it makes difficult to interpret something useful from multiplying the different triangles sides.

I request proofs using any / all of the 3 criteria:
(i) geometrical,
(ii) algebraic,
(iii) complex number based approach

---

Update : Sorry, for faulty question, as one comment to post has shown.

Comment: Try $a=1,b=0,c=0,d=1$

Comment: What are $a,b,c,$ and $d$? Are they related in some way that you haven't told us? Why would you assume there are right triangles involved, and why should we?

Comment: Maybe what you want is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285575/569098).

Comment: Maybe the objective is to find a criterion that makes this true?

Comment: @Mason Please see the first line of edited O.P.

Comment: Well on the linked page it has written $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=2ac+2bd$ in a few spots... But you have written a product above. For the product we use this Fermat's Identity: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$.

Comment: Let's delete this question and we'll meet you on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105330/equilateral-triangle-whose-vertices-are-lattice-points/105387#105387
If you post a question in the comments about how the argument goes through someone will surely pick up this discussion.

Comment: @Mason Have put a comment for the O.P. there, please guide why am getting wrong equality.

Comment: Done! Let me know if that helps. But you can do so there. As a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)= 2ac + 2bd$$

is not true for all values of $a,b,c,d.$

As a counter example let $a=2,b=3,c=4,d=5$

We get $(13)(41)=16+30$ which is not true.

Comment: In mathematics an identity should be true for all values not just for some. Of course your equation  is satisfied  for lots of values but it does not make it an identity.

Comment: @GuusPalmer I said it is not true for all values. I did not say it is not true for any value.

Comment: @GuusPalmer  "Prove" is used for identities and "Solve" is used for equations. You have used the word " Prove"  instead of the intended "Solve."

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry, but the claim is not true.  Let $a = c = 1$ and $b = d = 2$.  Then $(1+4)^2 \neq 2(1+4)$.

On the bright side, this explains why you were having trouble proving the claim.

Comment: Your answer has typos: $(a^2+b^2) = 1 +4 =5 = (c^2+d^2)$, so $25 \ne 2(1+4)$. But, how it will aid in understanding my fault is unclear still.

Comment: Good catch.  I've fixed my answer.  Good luck!